# How to set up onClickListener for both the list item and Button within list item?

Tags: android, listview, button

I have a listView where each list item has a button.  I want to set an onClickListener for both the list item and the button - I'm worried that it is only possible to do one or the other..

Here is my code for the adapter:

```
private class MyListAdapter extends ResourceCursorAdapter { 

    // In your ListActivity class, create a new inner class that extends ResourceCursorAdapter. 
    //This inner class is the custom CursorAdapter we will use to manage how data is bound to a list item:

    public MyListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        super(context, R.layout.row_location, cursor);
    } 

    @Override
    public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) { 
        TextView text_first_line = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_row_item_main_text);
        TextView text_second_line = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.location_row_item_secondary_text);
        ImageView flagIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.flagIcon);

        String row_text_component = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.COMPONENT));
        String row_text_position = ", Position " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.POSITION));
        if(row_text_position.equals(", Position Not Applicable")){
            row_text_position = "";
        }
        String row_text_action = " - " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.ACTION_REQUIRED));

        text_first_line.setText(row_text_component + row_text_position + row_text_action);
        text_second_line.setText("test text, test text");

        String risk = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(RMDbAdapter.RISK));
        if (risk.equals("Red Risk")){
            flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.red_flag);
        }
        else if (risk.equals("Green Risk")){
            flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.green_flag);
        }
        else if (risk.equals("No Risk")){
            flagIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.note);
        }

    }
}
```

In previous, more simple activities I set a onListItemClick for the list items, but how do I set the listener for the button??

Help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can have more than one listener in a ListView row. Simply set an OnClickListener like normal:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        // Do something
    }
});
```

This will supersede the OnListItemClick listener only when you touch the button in question.

Also please watch Android's Romain Guy [discussion adapters and efficiency](http://www.google.com/events/io/2009/sessions/TurboChargeUiAndroidFast.html).

Comment: Thanks Sam. Will give it a go and tick ASAP!